# How to send post request in websites?

Tags: python-3.x, post, python-requests

I have recently started studying about the requests module in Python and came across the POST method of sending data to websites using `data={something}`.So, I was curious and tried sending a post to google.com and wanted to see what I get back as a result like if I want to search `'hello'`. I always get a `405` error.I wanted to know why I get this error and is there even a way to send a POST request to any website where the user has to fill some data?

I am aware that I can also use `GET` but I specifically want to use POST.

I used this code below.

```
import requests

data={'q':'hello'}

headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0'}

p_resp=requests.post('https://www.google.com/',headers=headers,data=data)

print(p_resp.text)
```

I get a `405 error The request method POST is inappropriate for the URL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually if you want to search in `Google` you need to use `GET` method instead of `POST`.
Here is an example to search the word `hello`:

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.google.com/complete/search'
req = requests.get(url, params={'pql': 'hello'})
print(req.status_code)
```

output:

```
200
```

However if you use the `POST` method you'll have:

```
req = requests.post(url, params={'pql': 'hello'})
print(req.status_code)
```

output:

```
405
```

And if you search what's the difference between `200` and `405` status codes, you'll see that:

`The HTTP 200 OK success status response code indicates that the request has succeeded. A 200 response is cacheable by default. The meaning of a success depends on the HTTP request method: GET : The resource has been fetched and is transmitted in the message body.`

And

`The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 405 Method Not Allowed response status code indicates that the request method is known by the server but is not supported by the target resource.`

So, in this case you need to have another target that supports `POST` method in order to do your tests. A trivial target is your own local server that supports `POST`.

For more details see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)

Comment: What if I need to search something on some other website (like amazon or youtube). Would I have to use get for those as well. Also, is there a specific reason why these websites do not use POST, but go with GET. Because POST worked for me on debian.org .

Comment: @DJayGurung It depends on the service itself if the developer behind are supporting all the `CURD` methods or some of them.

Comment: So, is there any other way except GET and POST, if these two do not work ?

Comment: @DJayGurung See the link i've added in my answer.